# Manhwa where an orphaned woman is reincarnated into a story as a saintess candidate who is mistreated by others

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The manhwa is about a woman who grew up  as an orphan, and did archery up until she hurt her wrist. She then reincarnates into a story she read. She gets reincarnated into the body of a saintess candidate who is mistreated by others. She quickly stirred up a ruckus and left to go to her family's home. Her sister is deathly ill and her father was being drugged by her stepmother. I forgot to mention that during her journey to her family's house, she runs into a man who I believe is an emperor.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Behold the True Villainess](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/2gpaqm4/behold-the-true-villainess)***...?

> A girl from the modern world slips into the body of Niveia Aerber, the main character of the fantasy novel she was reading. To survive in Erathil, a world full of betrayal and monsters where she was destined to meet an early death, the new Niveia embarks on an adventure to escape from her fate. The old Niveia was set to become the next Priestess to serve the Grand Temple, but not the new Niveia. Instead, she runs away from the temple, from her archrival, Rosanna, and her fiancé, Duke Aetius Timothero. Along the way, she enlists the help of Prince Caeles, who is also on a mission of his own - to find out which noble families are planning an uprising against his kingdom, including Niveia's family. In this chaotic turmoil of love, loyalty, and treason, can Niveia create a better future for herself, and more importantly, can she ever return to the real world?

The female lead was a world champion in archery who fell into a slump after suffering an injury, and was subsequently reincarnated as a priestess character within a novel she'd been reading.

[image] [image]